# Error 'stencil init' when installing stencil-cli and base theme

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm trying to install the stencil-cli and base theme following the instructions in the documentation.  I successfully installed stencil-cli after I used a node version manager and changed it to version 4.6.1, but after cloning the theme and running npm install I get the following error after trying to run stencil init:

```
$ stencil init
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\dannytaki\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\bin\stencil'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:974:3
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you include a screenshot of the response after you use the npm stencil install command?

Comment: @Alyss ok done, I had already ran npm install to load dependencies too I believe. Anyway still same error when I run stencil init afterwards.

Comment: and you've run `npm install -g @bigcommerce/stencil-cli`?

Comment: Yes, I'll re-run it - that is to install the CLI.  Btw I'm from Austin too!

Comment: @Alyss I added a picture of command line output after running that command - still receive error with `stencil init`

Comment: Awesome (about Austin)! I'm asking someone else to get eyes on this because I'm not immediately seeing why you are getting those errors.

Comment: Can you add what files are in `C:\Users\dannytaki\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\bin`?

Comment: There is no @bigcommerce directory in the node_modules directory.  The only directory I see is one named gulp

Comment: there's another folder in the Roaming directory called npm-cache - in that there is a @bigcommerce directory.

Comment: Most people have had luck uninstalling and reinstalling node. Once you have uninstalled, run `node -v` to verify it is successfully removed.

Comment: Yep @Alyss, I was just going to post how I resolved this issue. I believe it was some kind of conflict with having both the NVM installed and node installed. I also had to deleted the existing npm install location (e.g. "C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm") so that the nvm install location will be correctly used instead.  I also installed the Visual Studio common tools. I'll answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure which step resolved this issue, but here is what I did:

1. uninstalled both my NVM (node version manager) and the existing installation of Node.  Deleted the existing npm install location (e.g. "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm") so that the nvm install location will be correctly used instead.
2. Reinstalled my NVM manger `https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows` and use `nvm install 4.6.1 64` to get the correct version of node required for stencil, and ran `nvm use 4.6.1`.
3. Went into control panel and updated my visual studios to include the `Common Tools` component.
4. Then, ran through the normal progression of steps as detailed in the stencil documentation.
5. `npm install -g @bigcommerce/stencil-cli`
6. `git clone https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil.git`
7. `cd stencil`
8. `npm install`
9. `stencil init`