# stencil cli error libsaass bindings was not found

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, bigcommerce

[Libsass bindings error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSJE5.jpg)
[image]

When i do stencil start I get an error message.
I am very new to cli so don't know how that happens and what is the solution.

Anyone help on that please ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please paste the error message you see when you run `stencil start` into the question, without it people are not able to help find out the problem.

Comment: Check out the steps listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42514587/4694817